# When i convert varbinary to varchar some new characters added. How to fix?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014, varchar, varbinary

i try to convert varbinary to varchar

```
declare @binaryData varbinary(max)
set @binaryData = (select "columnName" from "tableName" where ID = 1)
select convert(varchar(max), @binaryData ) as BinaryData
```

result:

```
ï>>¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"[]>
....
//(XML File(svg))
....
```

Why i get characters "ï>>¿" ?

Comment: @Larnu varbinary(max)

Comment: The characters are upper 128 ASCII characters (0x80 to 0xFF) and get displayed differently depending on the Encoding (Country/Language) that is used.

Comment: i try same code another computer result is correct 
result : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1.....
what i will do?
i change sql's Country/Language settings ? @jdweng

Comment: Usually it is a Windows setting.  It also may have to do with fonts installed.  Windows when it doesn't have the required font will substitute with another similar font that does have same characters for 0x80 to 0xFF.  The two characters are 0xEF and 0xBF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), where the bytes 0xEFBBBF are prepended to a file to indicate the encoding.  SQL Server is not introducing these bytes; they are present in your data.  To remove them, you can conver the column to XML, and the XML parser will ignore them.  EG:

```
declare @doc varbinary(max) = 0xEFBBBF + convert(varbinary(2000),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><foo/>' )
select cast(@doc as varchar(max)),  cast(@doc as xml)
```

outputs

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><foo/>   <foo />

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  The code displays correctly on one PC and not another.

Comment: Whether they are _displayed_ in every combination of client program and OS version is probably a different issue.